# How can I add bibliography to the resume class?

Tags: bibliographies, cv, resume

I have a .bib file with various references such as these:

```
@article{bellerby_probabilistic_2005,
    title = {Probabilistic and Ensemble Representations of the Uncertainty in an {IR}/Microwave Satellite Precipitation Product},
    volume = {6},
```

All I want to do is to include the publications automatically. I have seen the solutions posted here. But none of them are working for me. Could you please see why?

Using Texmaker.

```
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PACKAGES AND OTHER DOCUMENT CONFIGURATIONS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%
\documentclass{resume} % Use the custom resume.cls style

\usepackage[left=0.75in,top=0.6in,right=0.75in,bottom=0.6in]{geometry} % Document margins


\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{bibentry}
\newcommand{\bibverse}[1]{\begin{verse} \bibentry{#1}. \end{verse}}

\name{MX} % Your name
\address{73001} % Your address
% \address{} % Your secondary addess (optional)
\address{(000)~$\cdot$~000~$\cdot$~000 \\ test@outlook.com} % Your phone number and email

\begin{document}


\nobibliography*
\bibverse{dai_probabilistic_2014}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\nobibliography{master}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.